# How to put limit in text box and show remaining char for text box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created one text box but needed to show max character and remaining char.
Below is the html

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
    <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish both of these by running a function in the text box's `oninput` event.

```js
const maxChars = 10;
function updateTextBox() {
  let textBox = document.getElementById("textInput1");
  if (textBox.value.length > maxChars) {
    textBox.value = textBox.value.substring(0, 10);
  }
  document.getElementById("chars-left").innerHTML = maxChars - textBox.value.length;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="q1Remark" value="Remark" onclick="onButtonClick(1)" />
    <input class="hide" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" oninput="updateTextBox()" />
    <p>Remaining Characters: <span id="chars-left">10</span></p>
</div>
```